# Is it Possible to obtain Cyndaquil and Pidgeot in the Pixelmon mod for Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-pixelmon

Pixelmon is a mod for Minecraft that introduces Pokemon.

Like the title states, How can I catch or find Cyndaquil and Pidgeot? I think it might be available as I have seen it in process?

Comment: Wha?  Is there a pokemon mod for Minecraft or something?  That's the only thing I can think of that makes sense.

Comment: @fbueckert - Yeah there is: http://www.pixelmonmod.com/blog/

Comment: @Bosspvz2 - I've edited your question to make it clearer, but I don't really understand the last sentence, could you clarify?

Comment: @Bosspvz2 why don't you ask the mod's developer on his forums?

Comment: hello????? any answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to check a bit...
Anyways, in the new version of Pixelmon, 2.5.2,(and even 2.5) Cyndaquil IS made a starter.
And for pidgeot...
Pidgeot has apparently already existed, as it evolves from Pidgeotto.
       I saw these both in a Pixelmon 2.5 introduction video and the Pixelmon wiki at pixelmon.wikia.com.